# docker push to private registry: how not to specify a port

Tags: docker, docker-registry

When deploy a private registry per [this docker instructions](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-an-externally-accessible-registry), I have to specify the port in CLI to push the image like this:

For **http**(`80`), the command is: `docker push host.com:80/alpine`.
For **https**(`443`), the command has to be: `docker push host.com:443/alpine`.
If I mapped the port to 5000, the command is: `docker push host.com:5000/alpine`.

The desired effect is a simple push like this:
`docker push host.com/alpine`

How do I construct the `docker run` full command to achieve this when I start registry-container?

Comment: 443 by default, you have to put a reverse proxy (registry server side) to redirect to the port you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default port is 443, as far as I know, it can't be changed. But you can setup NGINX(or HAProxy) on another host and configure it to proxy all your requests to your registry, something like this:

```
server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name registry.company.com;
  proxy_set_header Host upload.expert;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://private.registry.company.com:5000;
  }
}
```

And then just `docker push registry.company.com/alpine`

Comment: Another catch I realized currently is the host name should be a FQDN name if we want to access private registry without specifying `443` port. Otherwise `docker image` will believe the host name is a repo in docker hub and tries to find it there.

Comment: For example your registry is registry.company.com. What short name did you try to use? Just `registry/alpine`?

Comment: Short host name would be `registry`. If I want to use it, it has to be `registry:443` so that `docker image` can recognize it is a host name.